# Using cgroups and nice with respect to the same process - does the order matter? What is the correct syntax?

Tags: background-process, process-management, cgroups, nice

I created a CGROUP on my desktop called ***background***. The purpose of this group is to run all my sysadmin scripts within its CPU limit of 10%. The group is created on every reboot with the following cronjob:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/cgcreate -t jerzy:jerzy -a jerzy:jerzy -g cpu:background && /usr/bin/cgset -r cpu.cfs_period_us=1000000 background && /usr/bin/cgset -r cpu.cfs_quota_us=100000 background
```

Despite this limitation, I still want my sysadmin scripts, already limited by ***cgexec***, never to take priority over the rest of my processes. Hence I decided to use the ***nice*** command, as in the example below:

```
cgexec -g cpu:background nice -19 prependPollen.py
```

Is ***cgexec*** in the above command limiting resources to ***prependPollen.py*** or only to ***nice***?

More general: does using ***cgexec*** limit resources only to the one command placed immediately after ***cgexec*** command? Does the same apply to ***nice***?

```
nice -19 cgexec -g cpu:background prependPollen.py
```

Would swaping the order, like in the above command, make any difference in the CPU usage/limiting?
Can both ***nice*** and ***cgexec*** be used in the same command/cronjob?

P.S. My environment: Bash, Debian 10 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both commands are preparation commands exec-ing the following command while keeping the property they changed. So the order here won't matter as long as the changed properties don't have any side effect changing the other (it's fine for these two).

```
cgexec -> nice -> final executable
```

will move the following process `nice` to be executed to the relevant *cgroup* and `nice` will change the niceness of the final executable (while keeping the cgroup).

```
nice -> cgexec -> final executable
```

will change the niceness of following process `cgexec` and `cgexec` will place the final executable in the relevant cgroup (while keeping the niceness).

Both commands will yield the same result. Both properties (*cgroup* and *niceness*) are automatically propagated to all children of the following process. So whatever is spawned from `prependPollen.py` will be in *cpu:background* and have the changed niceness too.

Any other similar command can be inserted at any place in this pipeline. For example `ionice -c 3`  could be added in first, second or 3rd place to attempt to limit the I/O effect of the python program with regard to other processes (while there are also *cgroups* doing a better job for this, it usually requires *cgroups* v2 to work properly).